# Angular nested Tree Doesn't look as expected

Tags: angular, angular-material

I created a tree structure using  Angular Nested Tree component, but the User interface of tree doesn't look as expected. For example, "fruit" is overlapping the word "expand more" and "vegetables" is overlapping the word "expand more" so none of the words are legible. 
can one help to fix this User Interface Issue,

Here is my code

```js
import {NestedTreeControl} from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MatTreeNestedDataSource} from '@angular/material/tree';

/**
 * Food data with nested structure.
 * Each node has a name and an optiona list of children.
 */
interface FoodNode {
  name: string;
  children?: FoodNode[];
}

const TREE_DATA: FoodNode[] = [
  {
    name: 'Fruit',
    children: [
      {name: 'Apple'},
      {name: 'Banana'},
      {name: 'Fruit loops'},
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'Vegetables',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Green',
        children: [
          {name: 'Broccoli'},
          {name: 'Brussel sprouts'},
        ]
      }, {
        name: 'Orange',
        children: [
          {name: 'Pumpkins'},
          {name: 'Carrots'},
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
];

/**
 * @title Tree with nested nodes
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'tree-nested-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'tree-nested-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['tree-nested-overview-example.css'],
})
export class TreeNestedOverviewExample {
  treeControl = new NestedTreeControl<FoodNode>(node => node.children);
  dataSource = new MatTreeNestedDataSource<FoodNode>();

  constructor() {
    this.dataSource.data = TREE_DATA;
  }

  hasChild = (_: number, node: FoodNode) => !!node.children && node.children.length > 0;
}
```

```css
.example-tree-invisible {
  display: none;
}

.example-tree ul,
.example-tree li {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl" class="example-tree">
  <!-- This is the tree node template for leaf nodes -->
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle>
    <li class="mat-tree-node">
      <!-- use a disabled button to provide padding for tree leaf -->
      <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
      {{node.name}}
    </li>
  </mat-tree-node>
  <!-- This is the tree node template for expandable nodes -->
  <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild">
    <li>
      <div class="mat-tree-node">
        <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
                [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.name">
          <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
            {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
          </mat-icon>
        </button>
        {{node.name}}
      </div>
      <ul [class.example-tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(node)">
        <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </mat-nested-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

Comment: Could you create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) showing the issue?

Comment: most likely you forgot to import icons in `index.html`

Answer (score 0):

You likely didn't include MatButtonModule into your app.module.ts file. 
That's what I was missing.

```
import { MatInputModule, MatIconModule, MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material';
import {MatTreeModule} from '@angular/material/tree';

...

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
        MatTreeModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        ...


    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [...]
})
```